# khtml2png php no output

Tags: php

I have installed khtml2png and run it via command line and it works great but when I run it from php in the browser it does not. I guess its the a permission issue but not sure? I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=faq)...

Why can't I run khtml2png without an X session?

> khtml2png uses the khtml library as it is used in the KDE webbrowser Konqueror. The library needs an X session to display the rendered webpage. There is no way (without hacking the whole khtml library) to redirect the rendered webpage to a file.

and

How to comile khtml2png with debug information?

```
gcc -O0 -g -ggdb -lqt-mt -lkdecore -lkhtml -I /usr/include/qt3/ -I /usr/include/kde/ khtml2png.cpp -o /tmp/khtml2png
```